# Unable to use fs and and webshot with Meteor on server side (galxy hosted)

Tags: node.js, meteor, fs, webshot

I am currently running a meteor app on galaxy that creates PDF based on input from the user.

I've been using webshot-node and FS to temporarly save the PDFs and then it direct download on the user side.

Because of some other bugs I solved, I deployed the new projects again on Galaxy, but it is now imposssible to generate the PDF anymore (nothing as changed on this part of the code).

The error I get is the following:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open /app/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/cv_resume.pdf 
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: '/app/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/cv_resume.pdf'
```

As stated, I didn't changed anything on the generation of the PDFs, so I'm wondering if anyone of you got similar error using webshot and FS on server side.

**By the way, it works perfectly fine on my local machine.**

Oh and here is the code of the generation in case someone would like to give it a try:

```
var myDocument1 = Personalinfo.findOne({ email: creator });
      // SETUP
      // Grab required packages
      var fs = Npm.require('fs');
      var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
      var webshot = Npm.require('webshot-node');
      var fut = new Future();
      var meteorRoot = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd() + "/../" );
      var publicPath = meteorRoot + "/web.browser/app/";
      var fileName = publicPath + "cv_resume.pdf";

      // GENERATE HTML STRING
      var css = Assets.getText('style.css');
      SSR.compileTemplate('layout', Assets.getText('layout.html'));
      Template.layout.helpers({
        getDocType: function () {
          return "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        }
      });
      SSR.compileTemplate('resume', Assets.getText('resume.html'));

      // PREPARE DATA
      var html_string = SSR.render('layout', {
        css: css,
        template: "resume",
        data: myDocument1
      });

      var options = {
        "paperSize": {
          "format": "A4",
          "orientation": "portrait",
          "margin": "0.8cm"
        },
        siteType: 'html'
      };

      // Commence Webshot
      webshot(html_string, fileName, options, function (err) {
        fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            return console.error(err);
          }
          fs.unlinkSync(fileName);
          fut.return(data);
        });
      });
      
      let pdfData = fut.wait();
      let base64String = Buffer.from(pdfData).toString('base64');
      if (fullName != "") {
        return [base64String, fullName];
      } else {
        return base64String;
      }
```

Hope someone can help me, I've been stuck with this for a long time now.
At disposal if anyone needs more info.

Comment: Does `/app/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/cv_resume.pdf` exist?

Comment: `meteorRoot = fs.realpathSync(process.cwd() + "/../" );` seems strange to me. Is that really how things on Galaxy are hosted? Can you rely on that?

Comment: Also, how does `cv_resume.pdf` get generated and placed on the server? Is this a static asset? If so, then using `Assets` is probably the better solution, as it doesn't depend on you having to figure out how the server lays out the files.

Comment: Hi @ChristianFritz , thanks for the answer. 
The path is actually what ```fs.realathSync``` is giving me, and to be fair, I have no idea if I can rely on this or not, I didn't find any documentation on that in the Galaxy docs. 

```cv_resume.pdf``` used to get generated, but not anymore, that what's seem strange. And I would really appreciate if you could help me use ```Assets``` as I never used it and doesn't really know how to do so.

Comment: Oh @ChristianFritz and the `web.browser/app/` is what was used in a local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarification. Seems like you just need a folder with write access where webshot can put the pdf and from where you can then read it again. In that case, just use `/tmp`:

```
var publicPath = "/tmp/";
var fileName = publicPath + "cv_resume.pdf";
```

**Updated** to use /tmp, so you don't need to create the folder first (in code).

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. I still get the same error as before ```ENOENT: no such file or directory. open '/tmp/webshot/cv_resume.pdf'``` I am wondering if there is any way to use webshot on the client side instead of the server side. Or maybe use something else to generate the PDF from a HTML/CSS page ?

Comment: did you create the folder?

Comment: According to the documentation of Galaxy, there is no need to create it as all the containers have read/write access to /tmp/ folder.  " Application containers are given read/write access to the /tmp directory and /tmp sub-directories. Application containers do not have read/write access to the /root directory or to the $HOME directory. "

Comment: Yes, but previously my answer used `/tmp/webshot`, which does not exist at first. Does it work now with just `/tmp/`?

Comment: No it doesn't unfortunately. I'm wondering if it's a problem of async as with ```fs.readFile``` I try to read the webshot which isn't created yet?